# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have searched far and wide and tried all of the suggestions in other posts but just cannot figure this one out. It's been days. Any help would be a relief.

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTbx8p2oCgcAQGQyqN8XeA1x) from Java Brains on Spring Boot and made it up to adding the database (video 27). I add the dependencies for starter-data-jpa and derby and get this error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed
```

I have not added any code to my app that deals with the database, I'm just trying to get it to run with the database dependencies. It runs fine without them. I have tried deleting the local maven dependency directory and downloading everything again. I have tried purging my local repo. I have tried messing around with different versions of things. This is all in Ubuntu on the command line.

Below is the output when running, the pom.xml file, and the dependency tree. I had to take out some of it because of the character limit but the meat is there. Thank you in advance

```
user@user:/SpringBootApp(master)$ mvn spring-boot:run
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringBootApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ SpringBootApp >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ SpringBootApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ SpringBootApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ SpringBootApp ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /mnt/sda5/projects/SpringBootProject/SpringBootApp/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ SpringBootApp ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ SpringBootApp <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ SpringBootApp ---

.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
\\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2017-12-30 09:56:30.788  INFO 6224 --- [           main] edu.cofc.App                             : Starting App on Paul with PID 6224 (/mnt/sda5/projects/SpringBootProject/SpringBootApp/target/classes started by paul in /mnt/sda5/projects/SpringBootProject/SpringBootApp)
2017-12-30 09:56:30.791  INFO 6224 --- [           main] edu.cofc.App                             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-30 09:56:30.883  INFO 6224 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5fcc4b57: startup date [Sat Dec 30 09:56:30 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-30 09:56:33.974  INFO 6224 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2017-12-30 09:56:34.006  INFO 6224 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-30 09:56:34.009  INFO 6224 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-12-30 09:56:34.174  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-30 09:56:34.175  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3300 ms
2017-12-30 09:56:34.427  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-30 09:56:34.432  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 09:56:34.433  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 09:56:34.434  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 09:56:34.434  INFO 6224 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-30 09:56:36.310  INFO 6224 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-30 09:56:36.352  INFO 6224 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-30 09:56:36.485  INFO 6224 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-12-30 09:56:36.488  INFO 6224 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-30 09:56:36.490  INFO 6224 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-12-30 09:56:36.518  WARN 6224 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2017-12-30 09:56:36.527  INFO 6224 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-12-30 09:56:36.579  INFO 6224 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-30 09:56:36.607 ERROR 6224 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at 
...
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at 
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted

[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject (AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at 
...
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init> (XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init> (MetadataSources.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init> (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:179)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init> (EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory (SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54)
    at 
...
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:844)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.189 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-30T09:56:36-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/140M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project SpringBootApp: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

and here is pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>edu.cofc</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringBootApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SpringBootApp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.9</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

and here is the dependency tree:

```
user@user:/SpringBootApp(master)$ mvn dependency:tree
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1 (file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guice.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SpringBootApp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ SpringBootApp ---
[INFO] edu.cofc:SpringBootApp:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.6.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:jar:8.5.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.13.1.1:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.9.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.13.RELEASE:test
[INFO] \- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO]    \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: which question answered this?

Comment: The one linked at the top of your question, in a yellow rectangle.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't realize it was a Java version issue. I changed my version to Java 8 and it worked. Thanks for the point in the right direction.